What is an example of a grammatical difference between Fuṣḥā at-Turāth (فصحى التراث) and Fuṣḥā al-ʻAṣr (فصحى العصر)?
I would like to ask about the two forms of Classical Arabic, the "hereditary" Fuṣḥā at-Turāth (فصحى التراث) and the "modern" Fuṣḥā al-ʻAṣr (فصحى العصر) also referred to as "Moden Standard Arabic" or MSA for short.
In:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Standard_Arabic#Differences_between_Modern_Standard_Arabic_and_Classical_Arabic
it was written:

MSA tends to use simplified sentence structures and drop more complicated ones commonly used in Classical Arabic.
Some examples include reliance on verb sentences (sentences that begin with a verb) instead of noun phrases and semi-sentences, as well as avoiding phrasal adjectives and accommodating feminine forms of ranks and job titles.

I don't understand this piece of text very much.

Nouns tend come after verbs (instead before) or are just omitted?
What is a "semi sentence" in this context?
What is avoiding phrasal adjectives?
What is accommodating feminine forms of ranks and job titles? Is it speaking to workers in some general neutral way?

What is an example of a grammatical difference between Fuṣḥā at-Turāth (فصحى التراث) and Fuṣḥā al-ʻAṣr (فصحى العصر)?

This questions is very broad and likely needs focus to be answerable. I'm also somewhat confused by your choice of terminology, Fuṣḥā (not Futzha, which seems to reflect an affricate pronunciation of the ṣ not known in Arabic, but present in e.g. Hebrew) is used to describe both Classical and Modern Standard Arabics. I've also never seen ḥadīṯa used to describe MSA in contrast to Classical Arabic.

In order to narrow the question down, I'd recommend reading the relevant wikipedia section and asking for clarification on specific points you find unclear. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_Standard_Arabic#Differences_between_Modern_Standard_Arabic_and_Classical_Arabic

@Tristan hello there ! Thanks to your helpful and guiding comments I have thoroughly edited the question and used the consensual terminology and I have explained what I have a hardship with and much focused the question only on grammar. A short answer of 1-5 examples (the common range for example/s in Stack Exchange I would say) would be more than enough for me, for now.

Although MSA purports to follow the rules of CA, even highly educated speakers cut corners on classical grammar.  The most glaring shortcut is the tendency to drop iʕraab, i.e., case endings on nouns and adjectives and mood endings on verbs, except in some special contexts.  Although this practice breaks rules, it is much too common to be called incorrect (and it deserves a lengthy discussion of its own).  It is barely noticeable in written text, since short vowels are unwritten.
Some other common practices in MSA were not forbidden by classical rules, just rarer:
SVO word order is increasingly common (notably in media headlines).
Perfect verbs are rarely negated with maa, but rather with lam + the jussive mood of the imperfect.  (The latter avoids confusion of statements with questions that begin with homophonous maa meaning “what”.)
Long iḍaafah constructs are often broken up, especially to avoid ambiguities that arise when one of the nouns is modified by an adjective.  Hence N+N li N+A instead of N+N+N+A.
